# Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a circle in the $XY$ plane containing $n$ lattice points in its interior.

Tags: geometry

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a circle in the $XY$ plane containing $n$ lattice points in its interior.

I was trying to use another lemma here that we can always find a point $(\alpha,\beta)$ in the $XY$ plane such that two different lattice points are at different distance from $(\alpha,\beta)$

Can we proceed using this or we have to take another method?

Comment: If you center a circle at $(\alpha,\beta)$ and slowly expand it, what happens to the number of lattice points in its interior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a circle (the line) contains two different lattice points $X$ and $Y$ (i.e., points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$), then its center lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $XY$. The union $B$ of the countably many bisectors of all line segments with endpoints in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a set of (Lebesgue) measure $0$, thus there exist in $\mathbb{R}^2$ points that do not belong to $B$. Choose any point $S$ not in $B$. Every circle (the line) with center $S$ contains at most one lattice point. Thus, when you are increasing the radius of a circle with center $S$ from $0$ up to infinity, the expanding circumference will pass lattice points one by one, never two or more at the same time.

Comment: You told that $X$ and $Y$ must be the ends of a diameter, but what if $X,Y$ are the endpoints of a chord?

Comment: Where did you see saying me that $X$ and $Y$ must be the ends of a diameter? Nowhere. If a circle passes through two different lattice points $X$ and $Y$, then of course the line segment $XY$ is a chord of the circle, and the center lies on the perpendicular bisector of this chord. I did not say that the center is the midpoint of $XY$ which would be the case were $XY$ a diameter.

Comment: Sorry I got you wrong...good solution